# How to test synchronization between C# code and Sql Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, testing, stored-procedures

In order to interact between SQL Server and C#, I'm using [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) object, Parameters and stored procedure.

My problem is that i have no idea, until i'm executing it, if it's still synchronized with database.

For example, if i have the following stored procedure :

```
create procedure psSync
(
    @Argument VARCHAR(50)
)
--do stuff
```

i will have in my code :

```
String myArgument="20131110"
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandText = "psSync"};
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Argument", myArgument);
//execute sql command
```

Everything here is fine.

But if i'm changing my proc to

```
create procedure psSync
(
    --Desync!
    @Argument Datetime
)
--do stuff
```

And forget to change myArgument to datetime, it's gonna crash and i'm often going to notice this bug too late.

I first tried to run unit test, executing the stored procedure in my development database with begin transaction and rollback but i don't like it as :

- it takes a long time
- it could run by mistake in prod
- it stores database config in test dll

So my question is :

How could you test all  sql links between C# code and SqlServer code (SqlCommand->Stored Procedure) quickly, efficiently and safely ?

Comment: This is one reason why ORM's were invented.  NHibernate or Entity-Framework or Other.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why you want to add that kind of schema validation ?
changing the Procedure parameter doesn't happen like that, right. who ever is modifying must be aware that this will require code change as well.

but any ways if you have situation and really need to do that, you have to come up with your own framework or set of API that you can call from C# code before any actual call to database procedure. I haven't seen these type of validation so far because it will add lot of overhead depending on is it just implemented for one or two procedure or across all DB call.

you can wrote SQL API that will return you DB all/selected procedures and there current schema definition. check this query. there are other useful information in sys.parameters table as well.

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(ssp.object_id) objectName
        ,ssp.name ParameterName
        ,sst.name ParameterDataType
        ,ssp.max_length
        ,ssp.precision
        ,ssp.scale
FROM sys.parameters  ssp
JOIN sys.types sst
    ON ssp.system_type_id=sst.system_type_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(ssp.object_id) = 'pr_test1'
```

the sample result will be like this.

yet remember that asynchronous issue can still happen if you do not come up with right frequency or when to get this information. the best you can do is just get this information right before that object call. and you know what will be the overhead of doing that all time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. I want to do schema validation because  you never know if a procedure is used in C# code or just for Db usage => Stored procedure modification doesn't always imply C# code modification. I understand that this question seems to show a lack of rigor but, in my opinion, this is the same logic that drives unit test creation. I will come back to this thread as soon as i will have implemented a correct framework for this test.

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with environment, like: DB, services and so on is a work for Functional and Integration tests. These test are slow and amount of them should be minimal.

If Unit Test takes long time, it's not a Unit Test.
Unit Test may check that expected parameter was set to SqlCommand and execute method was called. DB context should be mocked.

Corrections of such Unit Test is responsibility of that person, who updated stored procedure. Or there should be some DB specification with which Unit Tests should be synchronized.